# AngularJS REST calls - Property 'name' is undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, rest

I am making calls to the OpenWeatherMap API like this:

```
$scope.cities = [
    {name: 'Phoenix,US'},
    {name: 'Atlanta,US'},
    {name: 'Honolulu,US'}
];

$scope.reload = function() {
    $scope.items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cities.length; i++) {
        delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + $scope.cities[i].name).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope. items.push(data);
        });
    }
$scope.name0 = $scope.items[0].name //error occurs here
};
```

I am getting the error "Property 'name' is undefined.  I don't know why this error is occurring, since 'name' is a valid id in the OpenWeatherMap API.

Comment: You have a tag "AJAX". Do you understand what it means, right?

Comment: Yes, I know what it means.  I am making a GET request to a server, and the server responds back with JSON.

Comment: I think @dfsq is making a trollish comment about you missing the asynchronous aspect of AJAX. $scope.items is empty at the point where you're trying to access it.

Comment: `$scope.items` are not yet populated by the time you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started on this before @NitishKumar posted their answer. Mine is similar in many respects, although they use a factory and Array.map(), which is probably better form overall. Meanwhile, I kept everything in the controller as you had it and used angular.forEach(). They also help you handle returned errors, which I didn't do in my code.

I still provide my answer (along with [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9KeupatvJIPyNsFpsqTe?p=preview)) in case looking at your problem along with a few different solutions is helpful to you.

```
$scope.cities = [
  {name: 'Phoenix,US'},
  {name: 'Atlanta,US'},
  {name: 'Honolulu,US'}
];

$scope.reload = function() {

  var promises = [];
  $scope.items = [];

  angular.forEach($scope.cities, function(city) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
      $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city.name).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
      }); 

      promises.push(deferred.promise);
  });

  return $q.all(promises);

}; 

$scope.reload().then(function(data){
  $scope.name0 = data[0].name;
});
```

As mentioned in my initial comment on your question, your problem was that you were trying to set a scope variable to a value that had yet to be defined due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX requests / responses.

A good solution is to use promises, which help you to defer the setting of the scope variable until all AJAX requests have returned. AngularJS comes packaged with "a promise/deferred implementation inspired by Kris Kowal's Q", and [the $q docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) are worth a read.

Comment: controller always should be minimal

Comment: I point out the fact that you used a factory and that your form is better overall. But the code they included with their question has everything in the controller, and sometimes it's good for clarity not to introduce too much change in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

First Create a `Factory` for `$http` Request

```
  myApp.factory('cityData',function($q,$http){
      return function(cities){

        var promises = cities.map( function(city){
        var deffered  = $q.defer();

       delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

       $http({
         url : 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city.name,
         method: 'GET'
       })
       .success(function(data){
          deffered.resolve(data);
       }).
       error(function(error){
          deffered.reject();
       });

       return deffered.promise;

     });

    return $q.all(promises);
  }

});
```

Then Call it in Controller:

```
 cityData($scope.cities).then(function(datas){
    $scope.name0 = datas[0].name;
    console.log($scope.name0);
 });
```

See Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CduFr/)

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the `$scope.items` has not yet been populated. You can fix this by moving the assignment class inside the `$http.get` function.

```
$scope.reload = function() {
    $scope.items = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cities.length; i++) {
       delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
       $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + $scope.cities[i].name).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.items.push(data);
                $scope.name0 = $scope.items[0].name //move this inside the $http.get
            }
        );
     }
};
```